# fastest way to parse large binary file in python

Tags: python, parsing, binary, cython, mmap

I have files on the order of tens of GBs that are composed of a mixture of 10 or so packed C structs.  I need to be able to iterate through each struct in the file for analysis and want to be able to do this analysis in python code.  I don't need to write to the file at all.

I don't think numpy can help here because the files aren't just a single repeating struct.  struct.unpack I find is much too slow.

My idea so far is to use Cython and mmap the file, then iterate and cast the buffer to Cython C structs in the hope to avoid any unnecessary copying.  The snag I ran into with this approach though is I can't use the Cython C struct pointer directly and need to effectively write python wrapper classes which makes things a bit slower and tedious to write.  Anyone know of a way around this?

Wondering if there are other approaches that might work?  I haven't considered ctypes yet.

Comment: I actually use `struct.unpack` with large binary files and had no real speed issues. Did you try using `PyPy`? I think, since `struct.unpack` is using simple types, it should be highly optimisable by `PyPy`, so it might give you the needed speed boost.

Comment: @septi my basic Cython implementation takes 2 seconds compared to struct.unpack in CPython taking 76s and pypy 26s

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the copying is actually the problem? Something like this is already too slow for you?

```
st = struct.Struct('>QLB')  # whatever
while True:
    data = fp.read(st.size)
    if not data:
        break
    a, b, c = st.unpack(data)
    do_something_with(a, b, c)
```

If so, perhaps using mmap and `struct.unpack_from` can get you a bit more speed.